# not ... either A or B?

Tags: usage

Can the following (A) be paraphrased into (B)? I am not sure if it can because I think I have not encountered the same kind of structure as (B).

(A) I like ***neither*** cucumber ***nor*** eggplant.
(B) I
***don't*** like ***either*** cucumber ***or*** eggplant.

Comment: Yes, it can. See [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=don%27t+like+either&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

Comment: The word "either" is redundant in example B. Better to delete it:  "I don't like cucumber or eggplant"